# Cómo usar ForEach en este caso

Tags: c#, bucles, foreach

Tengo un problema

En C# después de obtener los datos del repositorio, usé un distinct para una columna llamada LEVEL, que arroja los siguientes resultados:

`foreach (var lev in Model.Commissions.Select(x => x.Level).Distinct()`

Y al imprimirlo sale:

**"1P, "9C", "1T", "6C", "7B", "5C", "4C", "2T"**

(Pueden ser más o menos registros dependiendo de la selección en el query)

Cómo podría usar el foreach con el distinct aplicado y obtener los resultados como muestro a continuación?

**"5C", "1P", "1T", "2T", "4C", "6C", "7B", "9C".**

La regla es que 5C SIEMPRE va primero y después el resto en orden ascendente, solo que aún no sé cómo poder lograrlo :(

Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto. Gracias.

Comment: Y si exigiste el dato `11C` en qué lugar debería ir?

Comment: Explico mejor mi pregunta anterior: Si tu ordenas números que son string, tienes que: `1,11,2,3`; en cambio si los números se consideran número `1,2,3,11` (natural sort). Como va ordenado en tu caso??? y además el formato es siempre un número de UN digito seguido de una sola letra?????

Answer (score 1):

Qué tal lo siguiente:

```
foreach (var lev in Model.Commissions.Select(x => x.Level).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x == "5C" ? string.Empty : x))
```

La clave está en proporcionar una función lambda en el `OrderBy` que devuelva `string.Empty` cuando el valor es "5C" y el propio valor cuando no lo es, de esta manera aparecerá "5C" el primero, ya que `string.Empty` es el mínimo valor de `string` y el resto se ordena normalmente

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Ah, no? No da esto precisamente la salida que está buscando? Primero que saga "5C" y lo demás ordenado?

Comment: Sería conveniente una explicación para el OP.

Comment: Y dime: ¿que supuestamente hace lo que *sugieres*? Y ¿cómo está solucionando el problema? Una respuesta iniciando con *que tal lo siguiente:* no es una respuesta que indique firmeza. Luego, no explicas absolutamente lo que has hecho y explicas por qué  es que soluciona el problema, la idea no es poner el código de la solución sino explicarlo para que la persona lo entienda y no solamente haga un copy-paste. No resuelve el problema po4que ni explicas ni demuestras que lo hace.

Comment: He quitado el comentario pero por favor. Explica tu respuesta porque entra como de mala calidad.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich, editada la respuesta dando una explicación